# Explain Plan with Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I want to take a look at the execution-Plans in Oracle. I tried this:

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ /*test4*/ * from tag
where key='name';

SELECT t.*
FROM v$sql s, table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(s.sql_id, s.child_number, 'TYPICAL PROJECTION')) t WHERE sql_text LIKE '%test4%';
```

The result was:

```
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |       |       |    22 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAG  |    14 |   714 |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

My problem is that the Rows are not correct, there are 3019 Rows with key='name'. 
This is an estimated Value.

My question is, how can I get the real value ?

Thanks, Andre

Comment: Please always past the complete execution plan; not just snippets. Since the optimizer is estimating only 14 rows, it's likely your stats are not up to date. So run dbms_stats.gather_table_stats( user, 'TAG' );

Answer (score 2):

You should use this command:

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'ALLSTATS LAST'));
```

And look for differences between the columns `E-Rows` and `A-Rows` in the output.

See also [How do I know if the cardinality estimates in a plan are accurate?](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/how_do_i_know_if)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL*Plus you can use the AUTOTRACE feature.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572619/difference-between-explain-plan-and-execution-plan?rq=1) for an example.

Comment: I set autotrace on and tried the option with autotrace traceonly  to, but it doesen't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
alter session set statistics_level=ALL;
```

Then run:

```
select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'ALLSTATS LAST' ) );
```